# Draw a circuit diagram

Tags: digital-logic

[image]I'm very frustrated about my homework.

Comment: do you know how to use a NAND to invert a signal? use DeMorgan's theorem to convert the expression to an equivalent with all NANDs

Comment: Homework questions need to show an attempt at an answer in order to show us where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- What is your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already know, memorize these equivalences:

[image]

They are exactly the same thing as each other.

The reason you might care here, with your problem in particular, is that your expression appears to need an **OR** gate so that you can **OR** together \$A\$ and  \$B\overline{C}\$.

So, expand out the lower left so as to see it like this:

[image]

Now, place the final expression at the end and work yourself backwards to fill out the details as you go. So like this:

[image]

Now, for one of the inputs you know you need \$\overline{A}\$. How will you get that? I've already provided the needed equivalence, above. So you should be able to work that one out.

But for the other input you have a ***new*** expression. You need to be able to work out how I got it from the local term inside. But this also isn't hard if you consider the equivalences I wrote at the top.

Then to make that one, follow the same procedure as above. Since it also is an **OR** expression, use that equivalent just as before and label the output with that expression. Then, again, work your way backwards, with the internal locals and then their inverse at the actual input. See what you have then.

That's the process.

Comment: I substantially shortened your comprehesive answer, because I think it shouldn't give the entire solution to comply with site rules. Of course that takes lots of your effort away. :( Feel free to rollback if you disagree.

Comment: @tobalt I didn't provide the whole solution, which would have required generating another NAND as well as working out its inputs and how to get them, plus the final composition to bring it all together. But I also actually appreciate the thought and don't, at this time, feel a strong need to roll things back. Either this one, as it is, or the earlier one are to me moot. So I'll leave it here, just as well as there. Since you weighed in, that's twice the count of brains. So I'll take this and hold short. ;)

Comment: @tobalt The consequence is that I wasn't able to show the process, itself. If one learns it well, it can be used over and over again in the future with far more difficult problems. So I miss including a glimpse of that process.

Comment: I also think that it is a shame that this quality breakdown wouldn't be used. I'll flag it for a mod, so maybe they have a better judgement as to what part of your answer is appropriate to reveal.

Comment: @tobalt & periblepsis (no `@` needed as you'll automatically get notified on your answer): Both of you kindly add great value to the site. I can see the concern about not wanting to give full homework answers, when there is no solution attempt currently given by the OP. On the other hand, the original answer isn't a complete solution (that *would* be crossing the line, but doesn't apply here). On balance, and it is a judgement call i.e. an opinion, the original more complete answer will be useful to future readers, *without* being able to be a copy & paste for the OP, so let's use that :)